# Mailing sending to removed users

Tags: civimail, groups, smartgroups

I had 50 people in a group and I had to remove 5 before i sent a mailing.
I removed the 5 and they all had the red removed next to them, so when I went to send the mail I had 47 recipients.

How do i stop those 2 getting the email?

Comment: is this a Smart Group or a regular group?  Sometimes the Smart Group caching results in odd behavior which is resolve by time or forcing the Smart Groups to rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of recipients is created during the mailing creation process (i.e. when you assign the groups to the mailing). This is primarily to avoid any permissioning issues when sending the mailing.

The easiest approach is to edit and save the mailing again, which will create a new set of recipients from the groups.

Alternatively if the mailing is still in scheduled stage, you could delete the relevant entries from civicrm_mailing_recipients